# Use separate audio devices for Skype speaker and microphone

Tags: skype-for-business

How do I use separate audio devices for speakers and microphone in Skype. Specifically a Bluetooth headset microphone and the laptop's built in speakers.

Comment: I believe this is currently impossible.